# Dropping multiple columns based on their name?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm creating a procedure/function in PostgreSQL. I have an array containing some column name and a temporary table as follows;

```
columns_names varchar[] := array['A','B','C','D'];
table PQR(A integer, B integer, C integer, X integer, Y integer);
```

I want to drop columns X and Y(i.e columns which are not present given array).

Is there any way to achieve this in single line statement?

Something like

```
alter table pqr drop column where columnName not in column_names
```

Comment: You can drop several columns in one `ALTER TABLE` statement. But you'll have to think a little and figure out which ones yourself.

Comment: I wouldn't mind using more than one statement though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do that if you are using function like you mentioned and language is set to `plpgsql`, then dynamic SQL is possible.

For example:

```
EXECUTE concat('ALTER TABLE ',
               attrelid::regclass::text, ' ',
               string_agg(concat('DROP COLUMN ', attname), ', ')
              )
   FROM pg_attribute
  WHERE attnum > 0
    AND NOT attisdropped
    AND attrelid = 'PQR'::regclass
    AND attname != ALL(array['A','B','C','D'])
  GROUP BY attrelid;
```

It will only work for one table, otherwise it will complain about returning more than one row.
If you need more tables, then you can use LOOP and `execute` query in it.